# Estruturação de projeto em múltiplos banco de dados MySQL é necessário?

Tags: mysql

Ao longo do ano desenvolvi um projeto de gerenciamento escolar com uma escola específica. O projeto foi construindo de acordo com as demandas e as necessidades da escola, mas, como não havia a intenção foi pensado somente para uma única escola. Atualmente outras escolas da rede demonstraram interesse em utilizar a ferramenta.

Minha dúvida surgiu pois eu não sou especialista em programação (na verdade sou iniciante) e não sei exatamente como o MySQL irá se comportar mediante a quantidade de dados, então queria saber considerando que dentro de um ano a a maior tabela (temos cerca de.umas 20 ao total) gerou cerca de 14 mil registros:

Seria mais correto mediante a obter um melhor desempenho do banco de dados fazer:

1. Posso reestruturar o projeto (no caso colocar elementos nas tabelas que indiquem a escola de referência, por exemplo, na tabela usuário teria um elemento para que os usuários da escola A não fossem vistos nem usados pela escola B).

ou

2. Dar a opção do usuário ao acessar o sistema escolher a escola (e salvar isso num cookie para não ficar pedindo toda vez, por exemplo) e a partir daí direcionar qual banco de dados usar, neste caso teria um banco de dados por escola.

Adicionando ao problema gostaria de aprender mais sobre MySQL, sobre sua estrutura, melhor forma de criar banco de dados, melhor forma de relacionar tabelas (já utilizo campos específicos e indexação de colunas chaves) e, principalmente, sobre a relação desempenho e máximos de registros suportados pelo banco de dados, se alguém tiver algum material para indicar ficaria grato.

Obrigado.

Comment: Basicamente, já que é uma rede, vai depender se elas serão integradas. Caso sim, reestruture o seu projeto. Quanto ao desempenho do DB, 14.000 registros é de certa forma insignificante (óbvio que depende do seu equipamento). O MySql está preparado para gerenciar milhões de registros. Porém, como você falou, como é iniciante, sugiro obter mais conhecimento sobre o tema.

Comment: @Filipe, obrigado pela resposta. Então, apesar de ser uma rede não existe (a princípio) qualquer tipo de interação entre informações das escolas (o que também não é a proposta da ferramenta que é utilizada para gerenciamento e monitoramento da escola(s))

Comment: Um aspecto que tem que considerar é a confidenciabilidade dos dados. Se os dados de todas as escolas estarão no mesmo banco de dados fica relativamente fácil acessar dados de outras escolas, mesmo que isso não seja permitido pelas boas práticas de sua organização, em compensação fica mais fácil obter informações gerenciais gerais. Se a confidenciabilidade for um aspecto importante a ser preservado então opte por um banco de dados para cada escola, tudo, obviamnte, atrelado a um bom sistema de login.

Comment: @anonimo obrigado pela resposta. Não existe nenhuma informação que venha a ser relevante de vazamento, digo,  nenhum dado sigiloso. Mas de qualquer forma a programação tem sido construída de forma bem amarrada com índices específicos onde retornam. Informações somente da escola específica.